# How to get the index value of an object using ContentAccessor?

Tags: java, docx4j

Let's say I'm trying to add content control for figure captions.If the figure caption already has CC then I need to get the index value of sdtRun from para and delete the SdtRun after retaining the Text value. So that I will re-insert the text value into para by using index value of sdtRun.

```
    int sdtcount = 0;
    int indexSdt = 0;
    List<String> text1 = new ArrayList<String>();

    List<Object> objects = p.getContent();
    ClassFinder sdts = new ClassFinder(SdtRun.class);
    new TraversalUtil(p, sdts);
    StringBuilder sd = new StringBuilder();

    for (Object o : sdts.results) {
        SdtRun sdtRun = (SdtRun) o;
        if (sdtRun.getParent() instanceof P) {
            ContentAccessor ca = (ContentAccessor) sdtRun.getParent();
            indexSdt = ca.getContent().indexOf(sdtRun);
            ClassFinder text2 = new ClassFinder(Text.class);
            new TraversalUtil(sdtRun, text2);

            for (Object o1 : text2.results) {
                Text tex = (Text) o1;
                sd.append(((Text) tex).getValue());
            }

            text1.add(sd.toString());
            sd.delete(0, sd.length());
            System.out.println(text1.get(sdtcount) + "indexSdt:" + indexSdt + "ca Size" + ca.getContent().size());
            sdtcount++;
            ca.getContent().remove(indexSdt);
        }
    }
```

Here i'm getting -1 as the value for sdtIndex.

Comment: Actually I'm getting index value of ContentAsseccor but SdtRun from it's parent.